# git rebase prevented by mistaken previous merge - can it be fixed?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase

I suspect I know the answer to this, but want to check as I hope I'm wrong.

We did a bunch of work on a branch and I had intended to merge this back with master as a rebase so that all of our history would be retained once all the pieces were in place. I put in a pull request and one of the reviewers approved it and did a "Squash and Merge". The merge was premature anyway and we reverted the changes on master but that left the new directories having a history on master. Now there is no option to "Rebase and Merge" (github has it greyed out). I tried to rebase the branch to master locally and it fails with errors pointing to the commit that deleted the previously merged files.

I've exhausted my git-fu. Is there a way out of this short of surgery on master and a forced push, which is unlikely to fly given the number of people who have the repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way out of this short of surgery on master

In one sense, no. There never was, from the moment of the so-called Squash and Merge (I say so-called because a Squash and Merge is not, in fact, any kind of a merge). What you did, revert, goes *forward*; it adds even *more* commits. The only way to "undo" actual history would be to *reset*. That is how you go backward. And the only way to do a reset on material that has already been pushed, is to force push.

However, I wouldn't say that all is lost, either. Sure, your *history* is a mess, but so what? At this, point that's just a glitch in the history; one day it will be lost in the sands of time. The important thing *now* is that `master` — meaning, the last commit on `master` before anyone does any more merging of any kind — should be in the right state (I mean, the right state of all your files). So just arrange that state, whatever it may be, and commit it right onto `master`, and carry on.

I would also like to say that I disagree with the premises of the question. You say:

> I had intended to merge this [branch] with master as a rebase so that all of our history would be retained once all the pieces were in place

That's wrong. A "merge as a rebase" doesn't "retain the history". It *lies* about the history. The way to retain the history of a branch is to *merge* the branch, plain and simple. Rebase is not a merge; squash is not a merge; *merge* is a merge. Merges are *good*. They are the cleanest way to preserve what happened while making it possible for the future to progress neatly. (Just to give an example, if you had done a real merge, then if you discovered the merge was premature, you could just keep working on the branch, fix it, and merge it again. As things are, as you've discovered, that isn't so simple.)

Comment: This is what I thought. I know rebase has plusses and minuses - it is rewriting the history of master ("It _lies_" - I like that). For reasons that I don't understand, our build engineering team disallows merges to master. So you can either squash and merge or rebase and merge, and the latter is the only option I have that retains history.

Comment: Well, yes and no. You could squash and merge to add a single commit to master, thereby satisfying the desire of the team not to “merge to master”. Now just walk away. As long as the feature branch is not deleted, the history is preserved. But it is harder to find, which is part of what I don’t like about it. You’ve destroyed the association between master and the branch; that’s silly, in my view, but it doesn’t kill the branch.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have the following situation :

```
             squash&merge feature in master
               |      revert the squash&merge commit
               v        v
*--*--*--*--*--M--*--*--R--*--*--* <- master
    \
     *--*--*--s--*--* <- feature
              ^
           the state of the `feature` branch when it was squash&merged
```

You can try to rebase `feature` on top of `R` -- the state of files in `R` could be close enough to the state of files when `feature` started modifying them, and this could possibly work without too many conflicts. It depends a lot on the modifications brought by the *other* commits on `master` (the `*` in the diagram above).

If that doesn't work (too many conflicts), here is another possibility to re-stitch pieces of history together :

```
# 1. starting from commit R :
git checkout -b wip R

# 2. re-revert R :
git revert R

# 3. replay commits s..feature on top of this new commit :
git rebase --onto wip s feature
```

This would discard the beginning of the history of `feature` (up to commit `s`).